# Searching for advices to build a timer for a game

Tags: android

Unfortunately my architecture does not work so i need your help.

The Problem which i want to solve:

I programmed a mini game in which you can select exercises like "run for 1 minute".

- showing countdown anywhere in app: fragment, activity, actionbar...
- do task after finish
- countdown should run ahead if leaving the fragment
- countdown should with the right progress again if i go back to the fragment

I tried to solve the Problem while implementing CountDownTimer. But if the countDownTimer is part of the fragment it will be destroyed if i leave the fragment. When i come back the countdowntimer begins from the beginning...

So i thought about a thread... but how can i display the countdown in the fragment and anywhereelse i want?

Will the thread alive until he is done? Even if i close the application?

So can you name please some keywords i can search for to solve the problem. Or instead describing a solution?

Thanks for your advices ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably put your counter in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which will run as a remote process and bind to that service everywhere you need to display the timer, then use the observer pattern to call a listener callback from you service CountDownTimer's onTick method whenever you you want to update the observers:

```
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(startTime, 1000) {
        //update after each tick
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            long seconds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
            long minutes = ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60) % 60;
            long hours = (((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60) / 60) % 24;
            long days = (((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60) / 60) / 24;
            if(listeners!=null){
                Log.d(TAG, "days:"+days + "hours:"+ hours + "minutes:"+ minutes + "seconds:"+ seconds);
                listeners.onTimeChanged(days, hours, minutes, seconds);
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            if(listeners!=null){
                Log.d(TAG, "timer finished");
                listeners.onTimerFinish();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: Seems to be the best solution. So i can even send push notifications like "exercise is over". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to make an actual countdown, because your threads should die when the appli leave and that seems really complex.

Instead, write somewhere (sqlite db ? file ?) the start time and the duration of the countdown running. 
Whenever you need to display it, query it, and do the needed process to update view, whatever view is in place. That answers easily (for me) all you specifications, without the threading burden, and only uses a tiny amout of disk space. Plus you can save all your countdown specific data without any problem, which will probably prove useful.

Comment: But the push notifications are crossing my mind. With this solution i can not send them.